# Why i am getting 406 not accepatble at client side status by the server and even my spring controller is not calling?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Here is my code 
ajax  get request code

```
$("#tabsss2").click(function tab1()
{
    $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            traditional: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "DataGridServlet.htm",
            cache: false,

            success: function (response) {
                         alert(response);
                      }

           });

           console.log("hii");
});
```

and controller code is what i have written as controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/DataGridServlet.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody JSONObject getReturnData()
    {
       System.out.println("control came into conroller");
       JSONObject dataObject=new JSONObject();
       dataObject=jqTabsGridDataDao.getTabsData();
       System.out.println("controller data:"+dataObject);
       return dataObject;
    }
```

so any one can help?

Comment: Can you post your controller as well?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/DataGridServlet.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody JSONObject getReturnData()
    {
       System.out.println("control came into conroller");
       JSONObject dataObject=new JSONObject();
       dataObject=jqTabsGridDataDao.getTabsData();
       System.out.println("controller data:"+dataObject);
       return dataObject;
    }

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/DataGridServlet.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody JSONObject getReturnData()
    {
       System.out.println("control came into conroller");
       JSONObject dataObject=new JSONObject();
       dataObject=jqTabsGridDataDao.getTabsData();
       System.out.println("controller data:"+dataObject);
       return dataObject;
    }

Comment: Mr Vinit Divekar now u can check once

Comment: is relative path in `url: "DataGridServlet.htm"` the same as `/DataGridServlet.htm` ... i.e. is the web page your AJAX is on in the same "path" as "DataGridServlet.htm"

Answer (score 1):

add the following header in ajax request

```
headers: {          
    Accept: "application/json" 
  }
```

Comment: sorry, I meant the accept header instead of content type